# How to use rasa in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, chatbot, rasa, anaconda3

I have installed Anaconda and rasa too in anaconda prompt, but how I can use rasa in Pycharm?
I have tried commands which are mentioned on official website `rasa.org` but I did not get satisfactory results.

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm, you'll need to use the terminal emulator (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html). First activate the conda environment where you've installed Rasa and then run the commands in that environment.

You can also just work from within the Anaconda prompt or your preferred command line interface.